# "Germany is a too dangerous country." - is this grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-order

If we can say

- XYZ is **a** very dangerous country

can we also say the following:

> Germany is **a** too dangerous country.

Is the above sentence grammatical? If not, why?

Comment: Poor Germany, it's certainly one of the most pacific countries in the world today.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, it's grammatical, but it's awkward; you'd never hear a native speaker say this.

You might hear, instead:

> Germany is **an excessively dangerous** country.
>
> Germany is **too dangerous a** country.

The latter is probably closer to the intended meaning, if I had to hazard a guess.

Comment: 'Technically, it's grammatical'. What native speakers commonly use _essentially defines_ grammaticality.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the state of being grammatical is a separate issue from what English speakers commonly use, especially when one considers the richness of dialects in English and how they vary with how they phrase things.

Comment: 'Technical grammaticality', when claimed to be different from what most (never mind 'all') native speakers would use, needs more supporting evidence than one person's say-so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Germany (subject) is (verb) a (article) too (adverb; modifying "dangerous") dangerous (adjective) country (object).  Sounds pretty grammatical to me.  It's poor style, but it's correct grammar.

Comment: Adverb placement is notoriously idiosyncratic. I've only found one grammar test not allowing the 'a too dangerous country to ...' order, but no authorities licensing it. 'A too-good-to-miss opportunity' is an idiom; 'a too dangerous country' / 'a too long holiday' / 'not a too far walk from the shops' ...  sound outlandish to the point of unacceptability to my ears. I'll keep looking for a better authority proscribing the general 'a too adj noun'.

Comment: Ah. Here's one (I couldn't find a better known author): [English Grammar: A function-based introduction, Volume 1
– T. Givón](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TWZM1bFFMSkC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=%22too+far+a%22+grammatical&source=bl&ots=B4aeBneoDA&sig=JXJPkj79B3dN_ivVAENoY_7TFk4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYrM_Qg9DUAhXBKcAKHVGjBeMQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22too%20far%20a%22%20grammatical&f=false) << Some adverbs, such as _too_, seem to be more appropriate as modifiers of predicate adjectives rather than [attributively used] ones, although an alternative order seems to accomodate them. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've noticed that Indian English sometimes (often?) uses *too* where others (e.g. BrE, AmE) would use *very* or *extremely*, etc.

Comment: @Lawrence But don't we assume that non-standard forms must be requested / labelled as such on ELU?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's commonly done, but it's not safe to rely on it. Even if such labelling is the norm, the OP's rep suggests that he/she is new to EL&U.

Comment: @Lawrence I'll rephrase. But don't we assume that non-standard forms will be requested / labelled as such on ELU, and treat all questions without such caveats as addressing standard English? Do we have to preface all answers with 'Except perhaps in I, J, K, L ...where they may do things differently, ...'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure. The intention behind my comment was simply to note the existence of an English dialect in which that particular "too" construct is idiomatic.

Comment: OK. But, like myself, the article I posted queries the grammaticality of 'This is a too big house' in standard English'. And you don't provide authoritative evidence (one way or the other).

Comment: And thy unkindness be like crooked age, / To crop at once a too long wither'd flower. / Live in thy shame, but die not shame with thee! / These words hereafter thy tormentors be! *—Shakespeare*